VBA Excel RTD server connection Active or Not Active
I have a spreadsheet with RTD server links to a COM add-in (by a third party).  A couple of times the connection has been lost and a excel dialouge box has appeared - saying "Excel has lost connection to the RTD server would you like to reestablish the connection". (wish I had screenshot)
What I need to know is - if there is a way to check in VBA excel if the RTD server connection is active or not.  Which action should it be check for? The dialouge boxes seem to stop any actions so I may need to turn those off?
A very simple method (that I thought of) would be to place an RTD function in a cell and if it goes to #N/A then my procedure to alert that the "connection has been lost" would be activated.
Thanks a lot for your help
I have tried placing a RTD formula in a cell and see what changes when I close the RTD server.
